# How to handle possible empty value in chains without null (no model tricks)?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm trying to add the RX Android pack library on a previous MVC project, wherein I'm trying to handle values from API responses to the Activity controller, passing by some controller that would do some additional operations on it.

The possibilities are that the value may be empty/optional/null by the API, in that case the controller would try to get the value from a cache storage, that also may be in the same condition, and finally pass it to the controller, where, depending the value, it would do some initing operation, or trying to make another API call with same mechanism, check that response, and then choose how to init the activity.

*Example code (signatures are wrong)*

In API:

```
Maybe<User> getUser(){
    //...
}
```

In Controller:

```
Single<User> getUser(){
    return API.getUser().switchIfEmpty(() -> Cache.getUser());
}
```

In Activity:

```
Disposable d = getUser().subscribe(user -> { if(user != null) init(user); else checkGuest();  } );

//...

void checkGuest(){
    Disposable d = getGuest().subscribe(guest -> { init(guest) } );
}
```

All of this would be incredibly cool and smooth, except for a consideration, **RX Java cannot handle null values**. We may say that since Java 8 where are trying to get over null values in favor of Optional values (**really?!?!?**), so the Empty/Maybe pattern would be appropriate.

So, let's try this...

In API:

```
Maybe<User> getUser(){
    //...
}
```

In Controller:

```
Single<User> getUser(){
    return API.getUser().switchIfEmpty(() -> Cache.getUser()).switchIfEmpty(() -> ???);
}
```

In Activity:

```
Disposable d = getUser().subscribe(user -> { if(user != ???) init(user); else checkGuest();  } );

//...

void checkGuest(){
    Disposable d = getGuest().subscribe(guest -> { init(guest) } );
}
```

I want to say that I hate and **cannot accept at all to modify my models** to add kind of additional attribute that would signs the instance as a Rx nulled instance, also because, this is an absolute violation of integrity, as of in any other method would be mandatory to check for that attribute, with a looooot of boilerplate.

Solutions:

- 1 I'm trying to handle this just by using single, and custom exception conditional checking in subscribe's error callable to decide where to proceed to next method in chain propagation, mixing functional and reactive programming.
- 2 I would have to modify my models, and use the RX Nulled instances in place of our beloved null values, but of course, also because I'm using Realm, and I can't even use polymorphism, and also, it violates integrity as said before.
- 3 Ideally, I would like to preserve the chain pattern and by using Maybe be able to execute a chain path if a previous value is Empty or another chain path if the value is not.

I would be happy if someone would feel like to front on the option 3, that would be the one that made me say "WOW" on the first time I seen a ReactiveX example.

Comment: Just wondering if using Java 8 Optionals + RX Singles would be the solution

Comment: what about using Kotlin models and nullable vars

Comment: Didn't tried to use Kotlin so deep at the moment, but I would suppose that RX in Kotlin would not support null propagated Single in the channel same way.

Comment: yeah but it'll be much easier to check the value through the stream and give a default value if it's null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found that eventually the best solution is in fact to... hold fast... to use Java 8 Optional!

First, this allows to keep the good old universal null like check pattern as always, so that we can't really need to forget about it, but also, to go on with the new technologies developments and so to conform to the new standard as we like to, and so to follow the new Java specifications as they come out.

This is also a "not" backward compatibility break, as in Android we can rely on some backporting dependencies to enable this before API level 24.

```
// support for optionals
compile "net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.5.1"
```

And moreover, this permits to use chained operations, conditionality, ReactiveX and a Single value as we coders prefer to.

```
    public Single<Optional<Model>> getMyModel(boolean offlineFallback) {

    return apiInterface.getModel()
            .map( model -> {
                if( model.isPresent() ){

                    MyModel serverMyModel = model.get();
                    MyModel savedMyModel = databaseRepository.getMyModel();
                    if( serverMyModel != savedMyModel ){
                        serverMyModel.setMyAttribute(true);
                        databaseRepository.saveMyModel( serverMyModel );
                    }
                    return java8.util.Optional.ofNullable( serverMyModel );

                }else{

                    if(offlineFallback){
                        MyModel MyModel = databaseRepository.getMyModel();
                        if(MyModel != null){
                            return java8.util.Optional.ofNullable(MyModel);
                        }
                    }
                    return Optional.empty();

                }
            });
}
```

Isn't this nice?

Comment: That's exactly what you'll achieve using Kotlin nullable Var but with less coding